# cannot connect a foreign key to a primary key

Tags: foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm new to SQL Server and struggling to link a foreign key in one table to a primary key in another table.  Here is what I have:

This is my first table

```
Create table "Employees"
(EmpID Int identity(1,1) primary key,
EmpNo Int,
EmpFName Varchar(30),
EmpLName Varchar(30),
JobID int references JobDetails(JobID)
)
```

I then created a second table:

```
Create table "Projects"
(ProjectID Int identity(1,1) primary key,
ProjectName VarChar(30),
ProjStartDate smalldatetime,
)
```

And tried to link the third table:

```
Create table "HrsWkd"
(HrsID Int identity(1,1) primary key,
ProjectID int references Projects(ProjectID),
HoursWorked int,
EmpID int references Employees(EmpID)
)
```

Incidentally, (EmpID) has a red squiggly line underneath saying that it references an invalid column in 'employees'.

If I then try to enter data into this third table like this:

```
insert into HrsWkd values 
    (1,1,50),
    (1,2,75),
    (2,3,85)
```

I get this message:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__HrsWkd__EmpID__68487DD7".
>      The conflict occurred in database "New_AP", table "dbo.Employees", column 'EmpID'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

I have been pulling my hair out with this for the last 2 hours.  I'm guessing it is something simple, but I just can't see it.

Thanks!

twotoast

Answer (score 0):

I don't work specifically with SQL Server for a long time, but you are trying to insert a record with a NULL Employee.

During the HrsWkd table creation you should allow NULL values. I'm not 100% sure about the syntax. Something like this during the table creation.

```
CREATE TABLE "HrsWkd" (
  HrsID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  ProjectID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Projects(ProjectID),
  HoursWorked INT,
  EmpID INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employees(EmpID)
)
```

Otherwise you are violating the default FK constraint.

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion.  I have tried it and the problem remains.  I think that I have mis-identified the problem.  It appears that the real issue is with "HrsWkd" table and the final line where I link to the Employees(EmpID).  The HrsWkd table doesn't seem to like the link to EmpID and says that it is an invalid column. . . . . .

Comment: I've notices the stupid answer after I've replicated your table setup. But I has to adapt it a bit to run on my local machine using MariaDB. It worked but like I said I'm using a different database engine. Something related with SQL Server and I don't have any machine here to test it

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out what the issue was.  I'm almost embarrassed to mention it as it was so obvious - but it may well assist someone else in the future.

The link between the primary and foreign was fine - the issues were entering data.

1. I hadn't added all the data in 'Projects' that I then tried to refer to in 'HrsWkd', and secondly;
2. I didn't enter the data into 'HrsWkd' in the same order as the columns were set up - so I was trying to add invalid data.  I had played around with the tables so much, trying different orders/outcomes, that my data no longer match up when I tried to add.

Oh well, this is something that I will (hopefully) never do again - so a 'great learning opportunity'!!!!